# Error: Could not create and deploy an application with boundless sdk opengeo suite

Tags: web-mapping, boundless-suite, sdk

I work on a web application with Boundless SDK opengeo 4.1,  I used the tutorial and followed the exchange and advice on this forum but I have some problems about adding plugins and deploying the apps. I need help if someone here can help me.

1-  I’ve already added all plugins I need for my project but I can’t add some plugins like gxp.Mesure, gxp.GoogleEarth 3D, gxp.FeatureGrid or Query Form which aren't enabled on the application. You can see below the application:

[image]

2-  I can’t make the package app for creating file.war to deploy with this application, I have a message error that you can see below:

[image]

3-  Is there a plugin that allows to export data like an excel format for the application with SDK clients?

Thanks !

Comment: What is the contents of the log file?